# Geocoding an event's address through the venue address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I have my `Venue` model geocoded and each `Event` belongs_to venue. How can I do `Event.near(current_location)` just like I can already do `Venue.near(current_location)`. 
in my `Event` model, I tried

```
class Event
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode

  def address
    self.venue.address
  end

end
```

Then running `rake geocode:all CLASS=Event` fails, because it Geocoder requires longitude/latitude columns, and `Venue` already has those, adding them onto `Event` does not seem like the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get an event near a location, why not just try to get an event near a venue?

```
Venue.near(location).events
```

This will allow you to find all events near a location via the venue they are associated with.